# Send emails via Sendgrid in cPanel

Tags: php, linux, email, cpanel, exim

I have a VM in Google Cloud Compute that I'm trying to send emails from. [Google doesn't allow](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) outgoing connection via port 25 and 465. I installed cPanel in the VM and I'm now trying to set it up to send emails via Sendgrid.

There's detailed documentation about how to do this on SendGrid's website but, after following the instructions step by step, emails are still not sending.

Here's a snippet of /var/logs/exim_main:

```
2016-03-03 19:22:21 cwd=/ 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -q
2016-03-03 19:22:21 Start queue run: pid=25773
2016-03-03 19:23:24 1abTCN-0003j0-Is H=smtp.sendgrid.net [158.85.10.138] Connection timed out
2016-03-03 19:23:34 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:47219 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2016-03-03 19:23:35 SMTP connection from (localhost) [127.0.0.1]:47219 closed by QUIT
2016-03-03 19:24:27 1abTCN-0003j0-Is H=smtp.sendgrid.net [108.168.190.108] Connection timed out
2016-03-03 19:24:27 1abTCN-0003j0-Is == example@gmail.com R=send_via_sendgrid T=sendgrid_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2016-03-03 19:24:27 1abPZb-0000qa-33 Message is frozen
2016-03-03 19:24:27 End queue run: pid=25773
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you are unable to connect sendgrid server to send mail. Please check your server connectivity  with sendgrid server

> 2016-03-03 19:24:27 1abTCN-0003j0-Is H=smtp.sendgrid.net [108.168.190.108] Connection timed out

https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200182038-Testing-your-connectivity-to-Sendgrid-s-SMTP-relay-using-Telnet